# Effects of a Stack Overflow (or Stack Exchange) prolonged outage on programming businesses economy?

Tags: discussion

I'm writing a general paper of my experience on the SO/SE platform for a knowledge management class and although I've read pretty much all the scholar papers on the topic out there, I've not found much on the potential effects of a long Stack Overflow outage on the economy (not necessarily global but in the programming/techonology area)? I'm not covering that specific topic since it's not an economy class and I'm not well versed in that but I am aware that a lot of people use the platform in their workplace and when the site crashed in February, it got me curious.

While I realize that this situation is not likely, I'm also wondering if anything is preventing it from happening? I'm aware the content is covered by CC so I figure this is one of the mechanics that would make things easier.

Any leads?

Comment: Considering that production code is running the economy, and that developers are typically working on the next iteration of code, I doubt there would be a direct correlation to the economy.

Comment: But it would hit the productivity of coders very heavily

Comment: While SO is nice and rather helpful, there were numerous professionals prior to the conception of SO (or EE, for that matter).  It won't kill productivity, except for those who aren't really up to the job.

Comment: What Matthew says. If your productivity is seriously impaired by SO going down - as in, you are unable to peruse other resources to solve your problems - you're doing something wrong. While there is always great lamentation in the twitterverse and such when SO is down, I doubt whether there are actual economic effects worth talking about, at least not in the short term. In the long term, if the site were to go away completely - yeah, probably, although likely impossible to quantify. Plus someone would likely set up a clone using a data dump.

Comment: @Emilie Since "crash" relates strongly to "economy" in a difference sense than a server crash (or the like), you may want to clarify the terminology. When I read over the title and first sentence or two, I was in the mindset of some sort of Stack Overflow economy that existed which, if it crashed, would affect some other economy. Or maybe I'm just tired and making things up! But something to consider.

Comment: @jprofitt: You're right, I didn't notice it while writing but after reading it again it was bugging me, will adjust.

Comment: @Emilie Glad to hear I wasn't being delusional ;)

Comment: it may be my poor English skills but your question sounds like if you were asking *`What impact does recent Ukraine and Russia conflict have on Forex market`*... kind of too broad for me to answer.

Comment: Stack Overflow is currently offline. Watch the markets!

Comment: @mehow: I guess it is, I just know I've used StackOverflow quite a bit and that was just for HTML/CSS which is not a huge part of my work (not a programmer). But I wonder what happens to the mass of passive users out there who may rely on it for their day-to-day work (and alongside, to the companies that they work for)

Comment: @Emilie I can't imagine anyone really relying on Stack Overflow to keep their jobs. That would be sick - we should all be getting paid for answering then ;P

Comment: @mehow While I agree that if you are only keeping your job because of Stack, you're in big trouble...I would argue that you don't have to ask or answer a question to have an effect on your productivity, just the availability of answered questions online is really useful to both active and passive users. I'm often left with the impression that the site has become an essential tool for many programmers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Are you asking whether the stock market might drop 10 points if Stack Overflow is down 24 hours?  There won't even be a blip.  Stack Exchange is a wonderful platform for asking questions and getting answers.  In fact, it's probably the future.  But its effect on the economy if it goes down, even for a week?

Negligible.

How do I know that?  Because Stack Overflow is not the primary source of information for the movers and shakers in the computing world.  Most questions on Stack Overflow are currently being asked by amateurs, not professionals.  That's not disparaging, or even discouraging, it simply is the way things are.

Stack Overflow isn't even the best source of information for the amateurs.  The best source of information for the amateurs is books, blogs, podcasts, writing code, writing more code, writing still more code, and possibly some classroom-style training.  It's not Stack Overflow.

Stack Overflow is currently the software developer's best personal computer psychiatrist.  It serves the same purpose as a psychiatrist; it *helps people get unstuck.*  It's not currently a good reference source, although it is good at providing clues for obscure problems, when someone has posted the problem and someone else knows the answer, and it happens to be Googlable.  For that function, it towers above ordinary forums, which are *completely and utterly useless* in that regard.

Is this an important function? Absolutely.  Is it critical to the functioning of the economy, or even important?  Not in any way.

Stack Overflow does produce the occasional pearl, a question and answer combination which is extremely useful to the person struggling with that particular issue.  And there isn't a day that goes by when I don't learn something new and interesting about programming from Stack Overflow and its sister sites that I didn't know the day before.

Comment: My question was too broad actually: I mostly meant for programming businesses.

Answer (score 6):

A prolonged outage of Stackoverflow has two effects:

1. New programmers heve more trouble to find their answers so they probably need more time to finish their assignments.
2. Experienced programmers can not spend any time on Stackoverflow to help the new programmers, so they have more time to finish their assignment.

I guess both effects will cancel each other so the net effect is zero.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the topic, but generally StackOverflow provides good quality answers to many questions, where google gives no other reasonable results.

There are some frameworks that are very good documented, like jQuery, but for example Dojo documentation is very poor, and PrimeFaces are full of gotchas and wtfs.

Disabling such a great resource as StackOverflow will result in more time spent on finding solutions to many problems, as well as with finding/implementing poorer quality solutions. But that effects would not be immediate, because it would affect software that is in development or feature/bug fixes to existing ones. Even if the functionality would be left intact, code would be made harder to debug and to maintain.

However, that would be only **temporary problems**, because StackOverflow is no Babel Tower and programmers won't be scattered and won't start killing each other, but would organize themselves in some other community.

It's not the StackOverflow itself that make developers more efficient. It's their ability to organize and help each other, and to learn from other people's experience.

Comment: I agree that another platform would probably be developed quickly but I think it's difficult to guarantee that it would function as well. It's not just the platform but probably a core of users and a culture that comes with it also.